# Getting "target unknown or block not implemented" when trying to sort an array of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am trying to implement a scheduler, and I want to sort an array `Tasks` of element type `Task` into a new pointer array `sortedTasks` of type `*Task`:

```
Task* sortedTasks[NUMTASKS];
//for ( t = 0; t < NUMTASKS; t++ ) {    sortedTasks[t] = &Tasks[t]; }
uint8_t t;

for ( t = 0; t < NUMTASKS; t++ )
{
  uint8_t s = t - 1;
  while (s >= 0 && sortedTasks[s]->NextRelease > Tasks[t].NextRelease )
  {
    sortedTasks[s+1] = sortedTasks[s]; // shift forward element of target which is greater than param[i]
    s--;
  }
  sortedTasks[s+1] = &Tasks[t]; // insert param[i] into target
}
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x3930 at pc 0x44b4
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x0000 at pc 0x44b6
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x0000 at pc 0x44bc
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x000a at pc 0x44be
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x392e at pc 0x44b4
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
msp430: =======================
msp430:io: read short at address 0x0000 at pc 0x44b6
msp430:io:     -- target unknown or block not implemented
msp430: =======================
...
```

and this goes on indefinitely. I assume it's some kind of pointer error? I tried initializing all elements in `sortedTasks`, and I tried just working with indices as `int`s (actually `uint8_t`s) instead of pointers, both to no avail. I am pretty sure the problem is in this snippet, since the code works without it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Who or what is giving these messages?

Comment: What is *Task* definition ?

Comment: data in `sortedTasks` array is uninitialized and you are using it for comparison in the first iteration of the loop. Not sure if this is enough to cause that issue, though!

Comment: Also, you are accessing to sortedTasks[s] where s equals to 255 since it is initialized as -1 but implicitly casted to an unsigned 8-bit integer. However I think you want neither sortedTasks[-1] nor sortedTasks[255].

Comment: @CRM, no he is not. When `t==0`, `s->-1`, `while` is skipped, then `sortedTask[0]= task[0]`. Next iteration now may compare it

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That might be the author's intent but the s variable would always be greater or equal than 0 as long as it is declared as an unsigned integer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie when *t* is 0 then *s* is 255, not -1, because *unsigned*, so dereference sortedTasks[0] not yet initialized

Comment: @matteomartelli. Your comment (which is correct) came after CRMs comment to which I replied. Same for Bruno.

Comment: Note: for insertion-sort-like things, there is also `memmove()` to move the existing entries up. (or down, in the case of deletions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
uint8_t s = t - 1;
while (s >= 0 && sortedTasks[s]->NextRelease > Tasks[t].NextRelease )
{
  sortedTasks[s+1] = sortedTasks[s]; // shift forward element of target which is greater than param[i]
  s--;
}
```

*s* is unsigned so `s >= 0` is always true, when *t* is 0 `s = t - 1` assigns *s* to 255, also when *s* is 0 `s--` assigns it with 255, with the effect to possibly access out of *sortedTasks* or dereferencing a not yet initialized pointer.

The minimal change to avoid that is to use a signed type for *s* and *t*.

Else more changes must be done, for instance :

```
  Task* sortedTasks[NUMTASKS];
  uint8_t t;

  sortedTasks[0] = &Tasks[0];

  for (t = 1; t < NUMTASKS; ++t)
  {
    uint8_t s = t - 1;
    while (sortedTasks[s]->NextRelease > Tasks[t].NextRelease)
    {
      sortedTasks[s+1] = sortedTasks[s]; // shift forward element of target which is greater than param[i]
      if (s-- == 0)
        break;
    }
    sortedTasks[s+1] = &Tasks[t]; // insert param[i] uint8_to target
  }
```

Note you do not save time using `uint8_t` or `int8_t` rather than `unsigned int` or `int`, or `size_t` and `ssize_t` which are the 'natural' types for the indexes